# Some problems with present perfect tense

Tags: descriptive-grammar

1. I have read all the questions and i have answered them. Or I have read all the questions and answered them. Which one of these two perfect tenses is correct. Do keep using have many times to represent that it is in present perfect tense?

Comment: The first one is a little more emphatic, but both are correct.

Comment: It's as Greybeard says. And no: you don't need to use 'have' each time to show it's the perfect tense.

Comment: You could just say "I have answered all of the questions." It's implied that you must have read them in order to answer them.

Comment: Actually this question was in my multiple choice test questions, i opted for the second sentence thinking that if i choose the first there would be repetition of have  but i was surprised that i was marked wrong.

Comment: If you are not going to repeat "have" , it would be better to say: *I have read and answered all the questions.*

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence sounds better as there is no repetition of words. So i would say :

> I have read all the questions and answered them.

is a proper way to write a sentence.

Comment: But the first option sounds much more emphatic - which might be a *better* representation of the author's thinking.